# Ruby: send HTTP GET request, receive JSON output - what is the fastest way?

Tags: ruby, json

My application will call Facebook API multiple times: [the example](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.stackoverflow.com/%22).

What is the fastest / most reliable way to send HTTP GET requests and parse the returned output in JSON format?

Should I use Curl::Easy? If yes, how does it deal with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "multiple times" mean? Twice? X times every n minutes? Thousands of times an hour?

Ruby has [Typhoeus/Hydra](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus), which handles huge numbers of concurrent requests. Processing the JSON is easy compared to handling multiple requests.

The [Times](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus/blob/master/examples/times.rb) example is a good starting point. Stick your JSON processing in the `on_complete` handler.

Comment: Then I think you'll like Typhoeus/Hydra. I'll add a link to a good example for it.

Answer (score 7):

Use [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

it includes crack for json. Use it like so:-

httparty "http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [crack](https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack).  Dead simple and just works.